# Conditional user defined variables in `xcconfig` file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, fastlane, xcconfig

Using Xcode 8, running on macOS Sierra I am trying to declare a conditional variable in an `xcconfig` file.

My project is using [fastlane match](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/match), so primarily I want to use [fastlane gym](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/gym)  to archive me app, but I want to be able to perform archiving manually as well (testing purposes).

What I want to achieve is something like this:

```
_ARCHIVING_WITH_CLI = YES // Actually want to check for some fastlane ENV variabel here, not sure how...

#ifdef _ARCHIVING_WITH_CLI
    _PROVISIONING_PROFILE_APP_STORE = sigh_com.mycomp.app_appstore
#else
    _PROVISIONING_PROFILE_APP_STORE = match AppStore com.mycomp.app
#endif

PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER[config=Release] = $(_PROVISIONING_PROFILE_APP_STORE)
```

But apparently that is the wrong syntax. I have tried looking for documentation but not really found any.

1. Can you help me with the `xcconfig` **syntax**?
2. Can you help me with
   **checking if archive was initiated manually or via** [fastlane
   gym](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/gym)
   (`xcodebuild` CLI)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation you're looking for: https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/

You can also run `gym help` and see supported parameters. `xcconfig` is like any other parameter in your Fastfile:

```
gym {
  ...,
  xcconfig: "STRING",
  ...
}
```

I'm not sure why you want to be able to archive manually once you set up `match` and `gym`. You should be able to run the same Fastfile from your machine, `match` will handle installing your cert, and you would accomplish the same thing.

See https://codesigning.guide/

Comment: Sorry for very late reply. I think you misunderstood my question. I am not asking how to make use of xcconfig from fastlane. Actually I dont wanna do that. I have setup my xcconfig as configuration in the project. I am asking how to declare custom bool variable inside a xcconfig and make use of that bool later in the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can set variables conditionally based on either sdk, architecture or configuration. The format looks like this:

```
<FIELD>[<condition_name_1>=<condition_value_1>][<condition_name_2>=<condition_value_2>].. = <Value>
```

where `condition_name_*` can be either `sdk`/`arch`/`config`, for details on the possible values you can refer to the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/adding-a-build-configuration-file-to-your-project/).

For your scenario, it seems you can do away with applying conditions based on `sdk`, or create custom configurations: one for Fastlane and one for in cli/manual use.